# How to filter strings in ListView

Tags: java, android, filter

I have an SQLite database that contains a table that has 3 columns, I'm using an `EditText` and a `ListView` in my layout. What I've done by now is applying a search using the `EditText` and displaying the filtered results in a `ListView`.

The following code is applied to the `EditText` called `myFilter`. The `words` is the `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {    
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
           int before, int count) {
        words.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
       }
   });
```

What I want to do is to filter two `CharSequence`s, for example I want to display in my `ListView` words that starts with a and b, can I do something like that (for example `words.getFilter().filter("a","b");` ? Any help ?